# save the state of button in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, sharedpreferences

[image]

am working on camera application i have two imageview one is auto and second is pro i want when i click on auto auto is selected and image icon changes and when i click on pro automatically auto view deselected and pro view is selected

```
autobtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            autobtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.autoactive);
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ModeActivity.this);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
            edit.putString("focus_value", "focus_mode_auto");
            Intent it = new Intent(ModeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(it);
            edit.commit();
            //MainActivity.grid.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

[image]

in the second picture pro is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SharedPreferences like this.

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences; 

sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ModeActivity.this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
        edit.putBoolean("focus_value", false);
        edit.putBoolean("auto_value", false); 
        edit.commit();
```

In your button event,

```
autobtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        boolean auto = edit.getBoolean("auto_value", false);
        boolean pro = edit.getBoolean("pro_value", false);

        if(!auto){
            edit.putBoolean("auto_value", true);
            autobtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.autoactive);
            edit.putBoolean("pro_value",false);
            probtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxxxx);
        }

        Intent it = new Intent(ModeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(it);

    }
});
```

Comment: in which activity we used shared prefrences

Comment: in the ModeActivity but you can access the values in any other activity

Answer (score 2):

**Your AUTO button**

```
autobtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        autobtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.autoactive);     //Change the AUTO image to selected
        proButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.proinactive);  //Change image PRO to deselected
        SaveButtonState("focus_mode_auto");                       //Save the button state

        Intent it = new Intent(ModeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }
});
```

**Your PRO button**

```
proButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        autoButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.autoinactive);   //Change the AUTO image to deselected
        proButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.proactive);       //Change PRO image to selected
        SaveButtonState("focus_mode_pro");                           //Save the button state

        Intent it = new Intent(ModeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }
});
```

**Save method**

```
public void SaveButtonState(String bState){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ModeActivity.this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPreferences.edit();
    edit.putString("focus_value", bState);
    edit.commit();
}
```

**Load method**

```
public String LoadButtonState(){  
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);   
    String buttonState = preferences.getString("focus_value", "DEFAULT");
    return buttonState;
}
```

Use `LoadButtonState()` in your `onCreate()` to retrieve the last states of the buttons when your application starts, something like:

**in your onCreate() method**

```
String buttonState = LoadButtonState();

if(buttonState.equals("focus_mode_auto"){
    aautobtn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.autoactive);      //Change the AUTO image to selected
    proButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.proinactive);    //Change image PRO to deselected
}
else if(buttonState.equals("focus_mode_pro"){
    autoButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.autoinactive);  //Change the AUTO image to deselected
    proButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.proactive);      //Change PRO image to selected
}
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can save the status for button in Prefresences as you already use and change the state of ther on both the click listener handler for both button

Comment: my first activity is main activity after main activity this activity is open when is select auto no doubt  it selected but when i came back go through main activity it again unselected how to save it

Comment: the save way when you press back onResume Method is called put your checks in onresume Method

Answer (score 0):

You are launching the activity before actually saving the value in `SharedPreference`, that's why you are not able to fetch the saved value in `MainActivity` (probably because you are trying to fetch the value in `onCreate` of `MainActivity`).

Just move

```
edit.commit();
```

before

```
Intent it = new Intent(ModeActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
```

**Update** Do this in `onResume`

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ModeActivity.this);
String selectedBtn = SharedPreferences.getString("focus_value", "nothing_selected");
if(selectedBtn.equlas("focus_mode_auto"))
    // Select the auto button
else 
    // select the pro button
```

Comment: hey Rohit how to save the state of auto until i deselect.

Comment: By default you save auto as selected in `SharedPreference`. On click of buttons check the value in `SharedPreference` and set new value. If initially auto was selected now save pro and vice-versa.

Comment: by default both are unselected no doubt i when i select auto pro unselected and vice versa but when come back this activity from other activity the both are unselected  how to save it

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the checkbox for this and create the selector for this checkbox.